# Java Atmosphere @MeteorService compile via cmd?

Tags: java, maven, servlets, long-polling, atmosphere

I am trying to understand Atmosphere API. 
Trying to compile a given example with CMD.
given at - https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Meteor,-WebSocket-and-Long-Polling

When i run the command - `javac -cp .;C:\lib\* MeteorChat.java`

CMD outputs an error

```
Error cannot find Symbol
@MeteorService
 ^
  symbol: class MeteorService
1 error
```

I do not know whats going on. I also included jars provided by Atmosphere website.

Please note: I am using basic structure (Servlet/Jsp) for my tomcat application. I am not using Maven.

i have to use Maven to overcome this problem?
or is there any solution to overcome this problem via normal structure in CMD.

Answer (score 0):

Which jars have you added? You need atmosphere-runtime-1.0..jar or atmosphere-1.1.x.jar, where x can be 0 to 12.

--Jeanfrancois